# Simpler way to effect OR with two \IfStrEq?

Tags: conditionals, xstring

Consider the pseudo-code

```
 IF mystring = "this" OR mystring = "that"
    THEN \dosomething
 ENDIF
```

Is there a simpler way than the following to implement that (inside the `\CheckString` command)? In other words, a way to more simply say `\IfStrEq*{\mystring}{this} or \IfStrEq*{\mystring}{that}` without having to nest the conditionals?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mystring}{other}
\newcommand{\dosomething}{At least one string matches}

\newcommand{\CheckString}{%...
  \IfStrEq*{\mystring}{this} 
    {\dosomething}
    % else
    {\IfStrEq*{\mystring}{that}
      \dosomething
    }
}

\begin{document}
\CheckString
\end{document}
```

In practice, `\dosomething` will actually be a set of several commands, and so the LaTeX code I show seems unnecessarily duplicative.

Of course I could define a separate, new command that consists of those several commands, but I'm trying to do this *without* defining a new command.

Comment: are you committed to xstring tests (which are not expandable so not amenable to being combined with inline expression)

Comment: I'm open to other ways! (It's just that I've become comfortable with `xstring`.) In case it prejudices the issue: I'm already using a `\IfStrEqCase*` construction in the same `.sty` file where this is needed. But no `expl3`, please! (I'm just not ready to start tackling that.)

Comment: If `this` and `that` are always non-equal then you don't need to nest, just try one after the other with empty else clauses.

Comment: And if you don't want to duplicate code and you don't want to define a new command then you can set a boolean to true in both `\IfStrEq` and then check for that boolean as a conditional for `\dosomething`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's essentially a one liner with `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\dosomething}{At least one string matches}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\CheckString}{}
 {
  \bool_lazy_or:nnT
   { \str_if_eq_p:ee { \mystring } {this} }
   { \str_if_eq_p:ee { \mystring } {that} }
   { \dosomething }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mystring}{other}
X\CheckString X

\renewcommand{\mystring}{this}
X\CheckString X

\renewcommand{\mystring}{that}
X\CheckString X

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even have more than two checks, using `\bool_lazy_any:nT`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\dosomething}{At least one string matches}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\CheckString}{}
 {
  \bool_lazy_any:nT
   {
    { \str_if_eq_p:ee { \mystring } {this} }
    { \str_if_eq_p:ee { \mystring } {that} }
    { \str_if_eq_p:ee { \mystring } {hey!} }
   }
   { \dosomething }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mystring}{other}
X\CheckString X

\renewcommand{\mystring}{this}
X\CheckString X

\renewcommand{\mystring}{that}
X\CheckString X

\renewcommand{\mystring}{hey!}
X\CheckString X

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does work, although I was hoping for an answer that avoids `expl3`. But why does this work even though package `expl3` was not loaded. (I'm using `pdflatex` from TeXLive 2019.)

Comment: @murray If you load `xparse` or `xfp` or `siunitx` or several other packages… Currently 153 packages contain `\RequirePackage{expl3}` and 185 have `\RequirePackage{xparse}`; there are surely overlaps, but we can say that more than 180 package require `expl3`.